# Import python module from another directory (NOT in site-packages!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pycharm, python-import

To give an example, my python files are structured like:

```
C:\
  folder1\
    file1.py
  folder2\
    file2.py
```

Let's assume there is a class named `Class1` in the module `file1` (and an empty `__init__.py` file as well, if you like). How can I import `Class1` in `file2`? I always get an "`ImportError: No module named folder1`" when trying to import from `folder1`; **things like "`sys.path.insert(0, '../folder1')`" don't work for me**.

Would I have to add "C:\" to the system environment variable "PATH" (note that I am **not** working in site-packages folder)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import a module from a relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

Comment: Don't think so, as I am working with two different directories. "from folder1.file1 import Class1" always gives me an ImportError.

Comment: Probably need to set your PYTHONPATH to have 'C:\folder2'.  And don't forget to add `__init__.py` to folder2

Comment: I don't have PYTHONPATH in my system environment variables. Should I simply add the variable with C:\folder1 as the only content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `__init__.py` in both the folders.

Then you can use the `sys` module to dynamically append to the python path

`sys.append.path(../folder1)`

`from file1 import Class1` will work now. (Tested on Linux)

But you still cannot do something like `from folder1.file1 import Class1`